# DATEVALUE(A$2)=TODAY() conditional format

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, highlight

So I am trying to highlight any row(s) that show today's date, however the rule I have created for this "A$2=TODAY()" does not like the format of the date in column "A".

The format is being created by a google form and an example of it is "1/24/2018 13:02:31". I have found that I can use DATEVALUE to get around this but I am not sure how to sure if I have the correct syntax  for the conditional rule. This is what I have tried but it does not appear to be working: "DATEVALUE(A$2)=TODAY()".

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to correctly solve this problem. I apologize if I am missing something obvious but sometimes I get these stupid mental blocks. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom formula. Just select 'date is' from the dropdown in Conditional Formatting and 'today' from the second dropdown (it is the default). Apply to A2:A.

Comment: Thank you for your help I believe I do need a formula because I wanted to highlight the entire row, which I should have specified. -Sorry